# MySQL Group multiple events occuring simultaneously on unknown datetime

Tags: mysql, database

My database is setup in the following way

```
date DATETIME
event VARCHAR(10)
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
[2016-03-20 12:00:00] [event1]
[2016-03-20 12:00:00] [event2]
[2016-03-20 12:00:00] [event3]

[2016-03-20 12:01:00] [event1]
[2016-03-20 12:01:00] [event8]
[2016-03-20 12:01:00] [event6]
```

I'm trying to match multiple events on a single unknown point in time

For example if event1, event2, event3 occur at the same time, I want to match and group that date returning the date

```
Match found at [2016-03-20 12:00:00]
```

I have tried writing some code but to be honest my sql knowledge is very limited

```
SELECT log.date
FROM eventlog log
INNER JOIN eventlog e
ON(log.date = e.date)
WHERE e.event = 'event1'
OR e.event = 'event2'
OR e.event = 'event3'
GROUP BY log.date
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `date` FROM eventlog
GROUP BY `date`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event) = 3
```